# JTable sort with dual tables to keep in sync in Java 1.4

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there a way where I can have a parent JTable sort value be passed and set the sort of a child JTable in Java 1.4?  What I have is a parent JTable of subjects with about 6 columns and a child JTable that is a subset of the parent JTable with the same columns.  What I need to do is when the user selects a item from the parent JTable and updates the child JTable, the sort is changed to whatever the parent JTable is at that time.  I had this working fine with Java 1.6 with the TableRowSorter class until I realized I had to use Java 1.4 - which the TableRowSorter class is non-existent.

Comment: i did not understand this parent JTable and child JTable concept. If all you want is sorting on table, then in 1.4 there's no direct API, you may have to write it yourself, or better copy the 1.6 TableRowSorter code and use it.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem that you need to provide a sort for your tables the way that `TableRowSorter` did, or that you need to pass the sort key from the parent to the child?

If the former, you could back your `JTables` with a `TableModel`s that contain row objects that implement `Comparable`.  You can then implement your own `Comparator` classes per column.  You can then, in your custom `TableModel` set the appropriate `Comparator` on your backing sorted Collection.

If the latter, I imagine that you are implementing `ListSelectionListener` in order to trigger the population of the child table with the correct data.  In this same process you can query the parent table for its current `Comparator` and apply that to the child table model.

Comment: The problem is that I need to provide a way to sort the way that TableRowSorter did.  I do have a custom TableModel, but I'm not sure how to tie that back to the child table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I got it working now with using the coumn index from the parent table to set the sort on the child table.